# iBeacon tech to bring location-aware app access to lock screen

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, core-location, ibeacon

hi  am using the ibeacon technology in my app ,now i have requirement of app icon should be display on lock screen left corner,when user enter in to the specific locations like restaurants,bookshops,showrooms.
Note: app icon should be show in lock screen left corner[app is not in device]is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

**This is possible only if the app is installed on the phone.**   This is how `CoreLocation` works as of iOS 8.

If an app does region monitoring (either for a  `CLBeaconRegion` to look for beacons or `CLCircularRegion` to look for geofence entries), iOS will wake up your app from the background when the region is entered.  When this happens, the app's icon will appear on the bottom of the lock screen.

**If the app is not installed, this will not work**.

There is a similar suggested apps feature that Apple controls that can put the icon of a suggested app based on geolocation in the same location.  In this case, tapping the icon brings up the AppStore to download the app.  But as @rkyr says, what apps get suggested are not under your control -- there is no API.  Apple decides what gets suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but it's not possible. It is called Siri suggestions, and you cannot control which app would be there. If your user will open your app when she enters this location everyday there will be your app. Siri doesn't have API.